Android phone models with user-writeable BP firmware (open-source Baseband Processor)
Which android phones utilize a Baseband Processor (BP) that's designed for power users/developers whoose firmware is easily accessible and flashable, by design?
While Google introduced WiFi MAC Address Randomization into Android 9, they've been dragging their feet on adding a similar privacy feature: Cell Tower IMEI Randomization.
My understanding is that this is a hardware limitation, because most Android phone manufacturers do not make it easy to modify their BP's firmware.
Unfortunately, because it's possible to spoof your MAC address but not your IMEI number, it's far safer (from a security and privacy perspective) to use WiFi radio networks on Android devices than to use SIM radio networks. However, if we had access to modify the BP firmware, then we could spoof our IMEI numbers on every connection, thereby greatly increasing the privacy of their cell-tower communications to be on-par with the current-state of WiFi communications.
Fortunately, there's a number of manufacturers of Android devices on the market that are built for power users: Purism, Pine Phone, Fair Phone, Shift Phone, etc.
My question is: which Android phones make the BP user-writeable, such that users can trivially spoof their IMEI number?

See also Where is the baseband firmware stored and how does Android interact with it?

In difference to Wifi where access to the Wifi is usually free or protected by a group password cellular connections are always identified on a per-user basis. Therefore no matter what you try you will always be identifiable as the SIM card contains unique, user-assigned cryptographic keys.

Please re-open. This question is on-topic. I'm not asking for a recommendation of "which do you think is best"? I'm asking if there exists a single device with user-writable BP. Answers to this question would not be opinion-based. They're empirical.

@Robert there are numerous privacy benefits to be gained by spoofing your IMEI because a user doesn't always use the same SIM or provider or tower with the same device. They may change countries or providers or SIMs. Randomizing an IMEI is an important best-practice for privacy and security.

Regarding the closure, the related meta discussion is Why is a canonical reference for Android versions considered appropriate but canonical reference for hardware such as sensors "not a good fit here?" (replace "hardware" with "criteria". OTOH, we stop creating a list of Android updates per model because there's no impetus in maintaining it). [1/...]

[2/2] Honestly, I'm somewhat sympathetic, but I just followed the current policy. Thus, I encourage creating a meta discussion about questions asking for Android models having such criteria, including defining the scope (preferably niche features, otherwise the big-list problem is still there). I'm interested in knowing the community's input on this. Meanwhile, since the existence of [hardwarerecs.se], we tend to suggest the user repost the question there.
